# Mockito - how to mock, and express expectations, on an abstract method of a class (i.e. a callback)

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, abstract, spy

I'm trying to unit-test an abstract class, therefore need to provide a mock implementation to the class' abstract methods.

I think I'm in a niche situation (!) since neither `@Mock` or `@Spy` seem to help.

- tried `Mockito.mock(SimpleClient.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS)` but this totally shatters my abstract class (creates it without calling the constructor, running into NPE)
- tried `@Spy` but this either requires an instance of the real class (which I cannot provide since it's abstract duh), or, it will attempt to call a no-arg constructor which doesn't exist.

(Context, although you should not need it: the class is a messaging client e.g. has `sendMessage()` and `abstract onMessage()` methods, and obviously I need to use the real implementation of `sendMessage()` and mock the callback `abstract onMessage()`)

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot provide a dummy implementation instead?  For example, `sendMessage` simply puts your message on a list which the test can read?

Comment: @JoeC yes, the reason is, I have in fact 12 callbacks and I feel ridiculous to provide dummies _and_ continue to use Mockito despite not being able to help in such a basic, commonplace scenario

Answer (score 0):

I found the following

- to go the first approach (`Mockito.mock`), [they have added the ability](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/685) to construct an underlying real object properly using an arbitrary constructor (And hopefully after that, Moquito goes on to "stub" each method as you express expectations on it, like the below):

  ```
  MyClass mock = Mockito.mock(MyClass.class, Mockito.withSettings()
  .useConstructor("stringArg", 17)
  .defaultAnswer(Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS));

  // ...

  Mockito.when(mock.onMyAbstractMethod(Mockito.anyInt())).then(
  invocation -> mock.callAnotherRealMethodOnTheMock(invocation.getArgument(0)));
  ```
- to go the second approach indeed a `@Spy` needs a created instance of the class, so in that case you really need to subclass it first.

**Extra note**: a separate issue, ugly as well, happens if say `onMyAbstractMethod` returns void, in that case the `Mockito.when...` syntax doesn't work due to a language limitation it seems, a fact which is poorly documented. One needs to do it the other way around and say:

```
        Mockito.doAnswer(invocation -> mock.callAnotherRealMethodOnTheMock(invocation.getArgument(0)))
        .when(mock).onMyAbstractMethod(1);
```